# Invertiblity of ST and TS for linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Could somebody explain why for any given linear maps S and T over a finite dimensional vector space V, ST is invertible if and only if TS is? Why is it so important that V is finite dimensional for this to hold true?

Edit: I am looking for an approach without using matrices or determinants.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is finite- dimensional, we can use determinants:

$$\det(ST)=\det(S) \det(T) = \det(TS).$$

$ST$ is invertible $ \iff det(ST) \ne 0 \iff \det(TS) \ne 0 \iff TS $ is invertble.

Now let $W=\{(x_n): x_n \in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N\}.$

$W$ is a vector space with $\dim W= \infty$.

Let $T,S:W \to W$ be defined by

$$ T(x_1,x_2,....)=(0,x_1,x_2,...)$$

and

$$S(x_1,x_2,...)=(x_2,x_3,...).$$

It is your turn to show that $ST$ is invertible, but $TS$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I was looking for a way to prove this without using matrices or determinants... Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $ST$ is invertible.  Then $\exists A$ such that $AST=I$ and $STA=I$.

Multiplying on the left by $T$ and on the right by $S$, respectively:

$TAST=T$ and $STAS=S$,

so multiplying the first equation on the right by $AS$ and letting $Q=TAS$, we see that $Q^2=Q$.  $Q$ is idempotent, and non-singular.  $SQ=S$ and $S$ must be of full rank, thus $Q$ is of full rank.

Thus (in the finite dimensional case), this implies $Q=I$, that is $TAS=I$.

Now we have that both $S$ and $T$ are invertible.  $S^{-1}=TA$ and $T^{-1}=AS.$

Thus, $TS$ is invertible:  $(TS)^{-1} = S^{-1} T^{-1}$.

The argument in the other direction is exactly the same (switching the roles of $T$ and $S$).

Comment: But where this does not depend on V being finite dimensional? What changes in your proof if V is infinite dimensional?

Comment: The first line shows that $T$ also has a left inverse, and $S$ has a right inverse.

Comment: I think the real "hole" in the proof, is that I have not (yet) shown that $TAS=I$.  Working on that $\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

If $T : V \rightarrow V$ is a linear map on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Then $T$ is injective iff $\text{dim ker }T = 0$. And $T$ is surjective iff $\text{dim Im }T = \text{dim }V$ (this fails if $V$ has infinite dimension). Furthermore we have the equation $\dim V = \dim \text{Im }T + \dim \text{ker }T$. Hence $T$ is surjective iff $ \dim \text{Im }T = \dim V $ iff $\dim \text{ker }T = 0$ iff $T$ is injective. So for a finite dimensional vector space we have:

$$T \text{ injective} \iff T \text{ surjective}$$

If $ST$ is invertible then $ST$ must be injective and surjective (I think of $ST$ as the composition of first applying $S$ and then applying $T$). This requires $T$ to be surjective and $S$ to be injective. Hence $T$ is also injective and $S$ is also surjective. So both $S$ and $T$ are invertible. Hence so is $TS$.